# Matching Passwords in Validation Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to code a validation or registration form that requires a Name, 2 Matching Passwords, and an Email. As of right now I'm hung up on the alert that pops up if the Passwords don't match. We're supposed to be using mostly If/Else functions.

```
var Name = $('#A'); 
var Pass = $('#B');
var Confirm_Pass = $('#C');
var Email = $('#D');   

if(Confirm_Pass.val() != Pass.val()){
  alert("Passwords Arn't Matching");
}else{
  alert('valid');
}
```

It's telling me at all times that my Passwords don't match.

Comment: Correct way: if(Confirm_Pass.val() != Pass.val()){

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `!` before `Confirm_Pass.val()`. You are already using `!=` for the comparison.

```
if(Confirm_Pass.val() != Pass.val()){
```

Comment: Im sorry that was just sloppy penmanship I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the extra `!` before `Confirm_Pass`

```
if(Confirm_Pass.val() != Pass.val()){
   alert("Passwords Arn't Matching");
}else{
   alert('valid');
}
```

Comment: Im sorry that was just sloppy penmanship I guess.

Comment: @Walker - very often all that's needed is a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `!` from condition:

```
if(Confirm_Pass.val() != Pass.val()){
  alert("Passwords Arn't Matching");
}else{
  alert('valid');
}
```